# Having trouble with recursive methods in c#

Tags: c#

Having trouble with recursive methods in c#. When compiled it should just display the total sumUpToo of all number for the given int, i.e
- input 10
- output 55 (10 + 9 + 8 + 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 + 0)

Im not able to find any info anywhere so if someone has a link to a website that can teach me how to go through it, would be greatly appreciated.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        public static int sum(int x)
        {
        Console.WriteLine("num");
        x = Console.ReadLine();
        int sum = 0, i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i <= x; i++)

        {
            sum = sum + i;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", sum);
        }
        public static int recursivesum(int x)
        {
        if (x <= 1)
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", x);
        else
           (x + Recursivesum(x - 1));
        }
```

edit * This is the adjustment seems to be working fine now, if im not mistaken. Thanks for all the help

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x;
        Console.Write("Please enter an integer value to sum up to: ");
        x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("The sum of all numbers up to and including {0} is {1}",x, recursivesum(x));
    }

    public static int sum(int x)
    {
        int sum = 0, i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i <= x; i++)
        {
        sum = sum + i;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static int recursivesum(int x)
    {
        if (x <= 1)
            return x;    
        else
            return x + recursivesum(x-1);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831790/having-trouble-with-recursive-methods-in-c-sharp ;)

Comment: Please post code that actually *compiles* - currently your method is called recursivesum but you're calling it as Recursivesum... and you're not calling it *at all* in your `Main`.

Comment: It helps to tell us what it outputs now as well.

Comment: I realize this is a toy example, but I feel obligated to point out that this is a horrible use of recursion.  When dealing with linear structures like arrays and lists, recursion usually only serves to add needless complexity.  This may be a nice problem to help you learn recursion but it does a poor job demonstrating why you would *want* to use recursion.  If you want to compute sums without using a "boring" for loop, use [`Enumerable.Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate.aspx).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A recursive function is a function that calls it self. You need a base case that will exit the function and a recursive case where the function calls itself with modified parameters. Your function should look something like this:

```
public static int recursivesum(int x)
{
    if (x <= 1)
        return x;    // this is the base case
    else
        return x + recursivesum(x-1);
}
```

So to use this function, you simple call it like this:

```
recursivesum(10);
```

If you follow the logic of the function you will see this will return 10 + recursivesum(9). recursivesum(9) will return 9 + recursivesum(8). So now we have 10 + 9 + recursivesum(8).

This will carry on until we reach the point where we have 10+9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2+recursivesum(1). Now if you look at the function again, recursivesum(1) doesn't call itself again. Instead it just returns x. So now the function will unwind and you'll get the result you expect.

One final note on recursion. Recursion can be a wonderful elegant way to implement some algorithms, but it has it's dangers. This site isn't called stack overflow for nothing!

Comment: Thanks for the tut. It does make a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 11):

Beginners often have trouble with recursive functions. Follow this pattern strictly and you will be less likely to go wrong:

```
ReturnType RecursiveFunction(ArgumentType argument)
{
    if (the argument is such that the problem can be trivially solved)
        return the trivial solution;
    // The problem could not be trivially solved. 
    // Break it down into one or more smaller problems.
    ArgumentType smallerProblemArgument = whatever;
    ReturnType smallerProblemSolution = RecursiveFunction(smallerProblemArgument);
    // We have solved the smaller problem.
    ReturnType bigProblemSolution = ...
    // ... use the smaller problem solution to solve the bigger problem...
    return bigProblemSolution;
}
```

So in your case:

```
public static int SumOfFirstNIntegers(int n)
{
    if (n <= 0) // trivial case
        return 0;
    // We have a harder problem to solve. Make the problem simpler:
    int smallerProblem = n-1;
    int smallerSolution = SumOfFirstNIntegers(smallerProblem);
    // We have solved the smaller problem. Use it to solve the big problem.
    int bigSolution = smallerSolution + n;
    return bigSolution;
}
```

Comment: You are correct, i have been having a lot of trouble with recursive functions, but i do have a much better understanding now, Updated post with correct output. :)

Comment: Perhaps for the same reason that beginners often have trouble with proofs by induction?  I think they exercise the same sort of mental gymnastics.

Comment: @GregD: They are essentially the same thing, yes.

Comment: I've referred to this answer many times throughout the years, thanks for this simple explanation of a difficult concept!

Comment: @reggaeguitar: I'm happy to hear that! Thanks for the note.